# можно ли как-то связать два исходных файла классов в java?

Tags: java, классы

Возможно глупый вопрос, но никак не могу понять, возможно ли связать каким-либо образом два файла классов, находящихся в одном пакете?[image: вот 2 класса, обведены красным]

Comment: а что имеется в виду под "связать?"

Comment: в одном файле только один public-класс. Если в двух файлах только один класс объявлен как public, то можно затолкать в один общий файл все. Если оба класса public, то только в двух файлах хранить

Comment: @Maxgmer например, в 1-ом файле выполняется одно какое-то действие, а во 2-ом другое и чтобы они работали вместе, в одной программе

Comment: @ТимурБаймагамбетов а если оба класса public, можно ли как-то, так скажем, передать данные из 2-го класса в первый?

Comment: конечно. Можно в методе одного класса вызвать Class2 class2 = new Class2(); и далее вызвать его метод class2.foo();

Answer (score 3):

То что вы хотите реализовать называется зависимостью.

В простейшем случае вы можете экземпляру одного класса передать ссылку на экземпляр другого и реализовать некую зависимость:

```
Class Human {
    Dog dog;

    void walkWithDog(int speed) {
    walk(speed);
    dog.runAround(this, speed *2);
    }

    void walk(int speed) {
    // do somthing
    }
}
```

Человек выйдя гулять с собакой не просто будет ходить, но и будет выгуливать собаку, которая станет бегать вокруг него с удвоенной скоростью. Если в первом объекте выполняется действие, то и во втором выполняется действие связанное с ним, кроме того из объекта человек в объект собака переданы данные о скорости прогулки.

Вы усложняете класс `Human`, но заставляете собаку бегать. Есть и другие способы наладить зависимости между классами, например Аспектно-ориентированное программирование.

Comment: А в моем случае, когда есть 2 исходных файла, такой способ тоже работает?

Comment: Если вы можете изменить код одного из классов добавив ему возможность управлять экземплярами другого класса - должно работать. Если нет - можете объявить еще один класс типа "Утренняя пробежка", который будет брать человека отдельно и собаку отдельно и раздавать им задачи.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать!